# Website that runs without Internet?

Tags: flash, offline-caching, offline-mode, offline-browsing

[allaboutrajini site](http://www.desimartini.com/allaboutrajni.htm) tells you to stop your internet connection to enter the site.I guess it determines whether the connection is on or off with javascript or something like gmail and qoura do.

But how can they store so much of flash animated content locally in the browser in such a short time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It loads a 160 KB swf file, Design.swf, plus a 134 KB sound.swf file.

> I guess it determines whether the connection is on or off with
>   javascript or something like gmail and qoura do.

It loads a XML file, config.xml, repeatedly, to check the connection, using ActionScript.

> But how can they store so much of flash animated content locally in
>   the browser in such a short time?

All the graphics are vector graphics, and contrary to what many would let you believe the swf format is pretty effective in storing vector graphics and the ActionScript needed to provide the interactivity.

As far as I can tell, there is no specific trickery going on for "offline-caching", it simply loads everything that's needed directly at startup, the 160 + 134 KB of swf content.

Answer (score 1):

It downloads a .flv file to browser. It checks connection and plays the flv if no internet connection is detected. Simple.

Comment: that's not just a flv video ..that is interactive content..flv videos are not interactive

Comment: @unussunu, swf, whatever. A Flash file can be interactive and totally self-contained.

Comment: If it's not an FLV... it's most probably an SWF.

Comment: yeah it's flash for sure..but isn't so much of animation big in file size?

Comment: btw my bad flvs can be interactive..didnt know they mean flash video :P

Answer (score 1):

It embeds normal flash content which i think  pings a server to check internet.

```
Source
------ 

   var so = new SWFObject("http://www.desimartini.com/allaboutrajniV1/Design.swf", "sotester", "100%", "100%", "8", "#000000", 'flashvars','Rajni=Cool');

    so.addVariable("flashVarText", "this is passed in via FlashVars"); // this line is optional, but this example uses the variable and displays this text inside the flash movie

    so.useExpressInstall('expressinstall.swf');

    so.addParam("scale", "noscale");

    so.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");

    so.addParam('flashvars','Rajni=Cool');

    so.write("flashcontent");
```

And there is nothing much in the site so it can load the swf in such a less time.